# Boundedness & integrability

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let's take a function $f\in L^1$
Does it follow that $f$ is also bounded?
Couldn't it be unbounded on zero-sets?

I'm working in probability theory (finite measure spaces)
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{n}$ on the interval $[\frac{1}{n + 1}, \frac{1}{n})$, regarded as subsets of the space $[0, 1]$. Then

$$\int f = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \sqrt{n} \left(\frac 1 n - \frac 1 {n + 1}\right) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n + 1)} < \infty$$

although $f$ is unbounded.

---

Much more interesting: Using the fact that $x^{-1/2} \in L^1[0, 1]$, we can make an integrable function which is unbounded on every open interval: Fix an enumeration $\{r_j\}$ of the rationals in $[0, 1]$ and consider

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} 2^{-j} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x - r_j|}}$$

as a function on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Ok then my suspect was right... I'm actually working on this problem:

Comment: Ok then my suspect was right... I'm working on a problem that use this: $\forall Z \sigma (Y)$ measurable & bounded: $E(ZX)=E(ZE(X|Y))$ for $X\in L^1$. In the solution they say at a certain point that for all g positive or integrable  this equality follow (taking g(Y)=Z). There are other conditions for this equality? Thank you

Comment: @sky90: The reason that you want $Z$ to be bounded is that $Z{\rm E}[X\mid Y]={\rm E}[ZX\mid Y]$ _only_ holds whenever the right-hand side is well-defined, i.e. whenever $ZX\in L^1$. Taking $Z$ to be bounded is one assumption that ensures that $ZX\in L^1$.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that elements of $L^1$ are not acturally functions, they are equivalence classes consist of functions. If you ask about functions in the equivalence classes, it can be unbounded on zero sets.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't follow that $f$ is bounded, it doesn't follow that $f$ is finite everywhere. And the two things are different.

We could have $f=\infty$ or $f=-\infty$ on $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ with $m(E)=0$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Since we usually abstract away from defining integral on sets of measure $0$ it could easily happen that $\int|f|<0$ (just take an integrable function and a set of measure $0$, define $|g|=\infty$ on this set and then $g=f$ everywhere else and you have $f$ integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$  while it is not true that  $f(x)<0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

Now, even if $f<0$ a.e. and $f\in L^1$ it could be that $f$ is unbounded. An easy example is in $R$. Define $f=0$ for all $x<0$, and think of a sequence of rectangles (characteristic function), standing on the x-axis, with midpoints of one side on integer numbers, with areas $1, 1/2, 1/4$ etc. such that each subsequent rectangle is twice as tall as the previous one. Then $f$ is zero everywhere else for $x>0$ except for when it equals the height of the rectangles. Since areas form a decreasing geometric sequence while heights an  increasing geometric sequence, your rectangles get thinner at thinner but at the same time taller and taller. By inspection, function is integrable, with the integral actually being 2, but at the same time unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = {1 \over \sqrt{x}}$ we have  $f \in L^1[0,1]$.